# Building gcc-4.1.2 on Fedora 17 (32-bit) VM

Tags: gcc, openssl, 32bit-64bit, fedora

I'm working with some legacy hardware, and I need to compile a customised version of opensslv0.9.8e onto a 32-bit system.

My Fedora 17 VM comes with gcc-4.7.2. Unfortunately, compiling the openssl version with this doesn't work, I get illegal instruction errors. I found posts [here](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/openssl-org-1546-openssl-0-9-8e-ans-gcc-4-2-0-td34680.html) and [here](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/openssl-org-1546-gcc-4-2-and-openssl-0-9-8e-td34683.html) that suggest that this version of openssl doesn't compile with gcc 4.2.0 or higher

*when compiling openssl 0.9.8e with gcc 4.2.0, some errors show up (see 
below). The test suite then fails with "instruction error". (The resulting 
programs also fail.)*

*I built and checked gcc-4.1.2 on the system where the reported error arose. 
I then rebuilt openssl with gcc-4.1.2 and could successfully run the test 
suite.*

My current plan is to build 4.1.2 onto my system. Unfortunately, when doing so, I run into the following error:

```
WARNING: 'makeinfo' is missing on your system. You should only need it if you modified a '.texi' 
or a '.texinfo' file, or any other file indirectly affecting the aspect of the manual. The
spurious call might also be the consequence of using a buggy 'make' (AIX, DU, IRIX). You might
want to install the 'Texinfo' package or the 'GNU make' package. Grab either from any GNU archive site
```

Then,

```
make[3]: ***[fastjar.info] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/charles/build/make/fastjar'
. . .
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I've installed `texinfo`, but I can't find `gmake` on the yum package manager.

What are the next steps I should take? I'm stumped at the moment ):

Comment: Maybe you should go back to Openssl-compilation, but adjust `-mtune` and `-march` options to the target system.

Comment: Also you don't have to worry on GNU-make: that is the default make on linux.